`Cannot invoke "java.io.File.exists()" because "archiveFile" is null` when doing `mvn spring-boot:build-image`
What causes Cannot invoke "java.io.File.exists()" because "archiveFile" is null when doing mvn spring-boot:build-image ?
$ mvn spring-boot:build-image
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< example:springboot >----------------------
[INFO] Building Spring Boot 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
...
...
...
[INFO] --- spring-boot:3.3.1:build-image (default-cli) @ springboot ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.893 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-12-28T09:48:54Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.3.1:build-image (default-cli) on project springboot: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.3.1:build-image failed: Cannot invoke "java.io.File.exists()" because "archiveFile" is null -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException


Same again, with -e
$ mvn spring-boot:build-image -e
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< example:springboot >----------------------
[INFO] Building Spring Boot 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
...
...
...
[INFO] --- spring-boot:3.3.1:build-image (default-cli) @ springboot ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.474 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-12-28T09:48:33Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.3.1:build-image (default-cli) on project springboot: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.3.1:build-image failed: Cannot invoke "java.io.File.exists()" because "archiveFile" is null -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.3.1:build-image (default-cli) on project springboot: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.3.1:build-image failed: Cannot invoke "java.io.File.exists()" because "archiveFile" is null
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:333)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
...
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.3.1:build-image failed: Cannot invoke "java.io.File.exists()" because "archiveFile" is null
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
...
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.io.File.exists()" because "archiveFile" is null
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.BuildImageMojo.getArchiveFile (BuildImageMojo.java:306)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.BuildImageMojo.getBuildRequest (BuildImageMojo.java:261)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.BuildImageMojo.buildImage (BuildImageMojo.java:251)
...
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException


This is caused by use of <finalName> in the build section of pom.xml.
<build>
    <!-- `finalName` stops `mvn spring-boot:build-image` from working -->
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.${buildNumber}</finalName>
    ...
</build>

This is because inside method getArchiveFile() of BuildImageMojo.java, it is looking for a certain exact format of archive file, specified by getTargetFile(this.finalName, this.classifier, this.sourceDirectory). Changing finalName means it can no longer find this file.
private File getArchiveFile() {
    // We can't use 'project.getArtifact().getFile()' because package can be done in a
    // forked lifecycle and will be null
    File archiveFile = getTargetFile(this.finalName, this.classifier, this.sourceDirectory);
    if (!archiveFile.exists()) {
        archiveFile = getSourceArtifact(this.classifier).getFile();
    }
    if (!archiveFile.exists()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("A jar or war file is required for building image");
    }
    return archiveFile;
}

Link to code in Github
